# Unicode characters not working in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a string from cloud firestore that is in unicode format and display it in my flutter app.

> c. 10\u{207B}\u{2076} seconds: Hadron epoch begins: As the universe cools to about 10\u{00B9}\u{2070} kelvin, a quark-hadron transition takes place in which quarks bind to form more complex particles—hadrons. This quark confinement includes the formation of protons and neutrons (nucleons), the building blocks of atomic nuclei.

When I store it as a string and display it in a RichText widget, it is working fine:

```
Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);
String temp1 = "c. 10\u{207B}\u{2076} seconds: Hadron epoch begins: As the universe cools to about 10\u{00B9}\u{2070} kelvin, a quark-hadron transition takes place in which quarks bind to form more complex particles—hadrons. This quark confinement includes the formation of protons and neutrons (nucleons), the building blocks of atomic nuclei.";

return Padding(
  key: ValueKey(record.name),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
  child: Container(
    child: RichText(
      text: TextSpan(text: temp1, style: defaultStyle),
    ),
  ),
);}
```

[image: This is how it displays when it stored as a string]

Whereas if I try to store it on cloud firestore and use the same RichText widget, it is not working. It is just printing as it is.:

```
Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
final record = Record.fromSnapshot(data);
//String temp1 = "c. 10\u{207B}\u{2076} seconds: Hadron epoch begins: As the universe cools to about 10\u{00B9}\u{2070} kelvin, a quark-hadron transition takes place in which quarks bind to form more complex particles—hadrons. This quark confinement includes the formation of protons and neutrons (nucleons), the building blocks of atomic nuclei.";

return Padding(
  key: ValueKey(record.name),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
  child: Container(
    child: RichText(
      text: TextSpan(text: record.name, style: defaultStyle),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

[image: This is how it show when I get the string from firestore]

Please provide a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Store your data as you want to show in your Widgets (UTF-8), don't need to use unicode on that case.

[image]

```
 TextSpan(text: text, style: defaultStyle)
```

Comment: I'm unable to store it like that. If I try to copy paste the text that has superscripts, it is just being pasted normally without any superscripts.

Comment: That's weird, I can do it directly on Firestore

Comment: how do you store the values on firestore, could you upload a screenshot ?

Comment: ok, now try to use unicode on firestore to see how it looks like and add the image again

Comment: I guess this is a problem with either windows or the browser. When I try to paste the text in the address bar of browser, it is being pasted normally without any superscripts. This is happening in Opera & Edge. Whereas if I try to paste it in wordpad, it is being pasted fine with superscripts. May I know which browser and OS you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185534/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-prasanth-kanna).